# Assets saved to asset browser are at a strange angle

Tags: asset-browser

I've recently returned to blender and I'm starting to use the asset browser.  But I'm finding that some models I've marked as assets show up in the asset browser at a strange angle

[image]

In the original blend file the asset is at the right angle

[image]

But if you drag them into a new blend file they aren't correctly aligned

[image]

Comment: Hello, is the transform orientation of the gizmo set to local or global coordinates ?

Comment: I thought they were, both items were added to a blend file opened with default settings.  But I'll check again.